# "I was locked in an elevator for five hours" vs. "I have been locked for five hours"

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice, past-simple, present-continuous

In a hypothetical situation, I was in a lift and suddenly it stopped and I got stuck in it for five hours.

So in this situation what would I say?

> *"I **was locked** in it for five hours."*
>
> OR
>
> *"I **have been locked** for five hours."*

According to me, if something started in the past and is still happening, then one should use present perfect continuous but my confusion is that if we use present perfect continuous here, then it may also mean that someone locked me in the elevator (Passive form).

e.g. "I have been locked by someone."

So please tell me which sentence would be appropriate here to say that I was inside an elevator for five hours.

Comment: Are you calling someone from the elevator in which you are still locked, or are you relating the incident later after getting out?

Comment: @Shoe suppose I am telling this incident to one of my friends later after getting out.

Comment: @HotLicks "Fred, yesterday I was locked in an elevator for five hours"  in this place can't you also say I had been locked in an elevator for five hours. I mean isn't it wrong to use past participle for something which happened for a longer duration?

Comment: If you say "Fred, yesterday I had been locked in an elevator for five hours" then you produce an expectation that the statement will be followed by the mention of some subsequent event.

Comment: PPC is "I ***have been locking*** up in this elevator." To be locked or closed inside an elevator, the progressive (continuous) tense is not used. To **be** locked inside is NOT a dynamic verb. The **Present Perfect** is the tense used in the 2nd example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA- So, my android arm works just fine except I have been locking up in this elevator.  Always this elevator; nowhere else.  I don't know why.

Comment: @Jim oh, so you're saying "I've been locking (up) in this elevator [for five hours]" is idiomatic, is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA- Not in OP's context, but if you had bionic limb that refused to move every time you got into that elevator, then it would be perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: You could say both, but they mean very different things: the first means you were previously locked in an elevator, but you’re now not. The second means that ***you are the elevator***, that someone came and locked you five hours ago (probably right after they managed to get some guy called Kuldeep out of you), and no one has unlocked you yet. In normal usage, it should be clear which one makes most sense.

Comment: 1) You mention continuous aspect in your question but your example does not use  an -_ing_ form.  2) I'm confused by these contradictory statements: "According to me, if something started in the past and is still happening…" and "suppose I am telling this incident to one of my friends later after getting out."  These two cases would usually need different verbs/verb phrases.   3) I wonder whether your question is _was_ vs _have been_ or whether it is _was_ vs _**had** been_?

Answer (score 14):

If you are relating an incident which started and finished sometime in the past with no present relevance, then you would not use the present perfect. So, *I was locked in the elevator for five hours* is the likeliest choice for your context.

If you call someone from the elevator to report that you are trapped, then *I have been locked in the elevator for five hours* is the correct choice. (It uses the simple present perfect, not the continuous form.)

It is possible, however, to use the present perfect, even after you have escaped - but only if there is a a present relevance. For example, your friend sees you in the corridor gulping down a bottle of water and says: *Are you OK? You look awful.* Then  *I've been locked in the elevator for five hours* is the probable reply.

As to your comment about the passive, calling someone from the elevator and saying *I have been locked in here for five hours* is ambiguous. It could mean that someone has locked you in and told you that you will remain there for five hours (i.e. *I have been locked ...* is the passive voice).

More likely, however, it means that the elevator has stopped functioning and you are trapped. This grammatical construction uses the copula (the verb *to be*) plus the past participle *locked* functioning as an adjective.